# Do we know who the descendants of Mary mother of Jesus were?

Tags: protestantism, virgin-mary, genealogy

So I am not asking about Mary and Joseph's genealogy. I am asking about their children's descendants.  So Jesus's siblings' children, their children's children, etc.  Whenever I search for this, I only receive results about their family history genealogy.  So essentially, what happened to Jesus's nieces and nephews?

Comment: Yes, from the Protestant view.

Comment: @MattGutting Quick question: Does the Catholic Church believe that Mary intended herself to be consecrated virgin before the annunciation, and that Joseph "married" her to be a protector, not a full husband, and that became the basis of the Catholic doctrine of the perpetual virginity of Mary?

Comment: @gratefuldisciple The Catholic Church believes that [the marriage between Mary and Joseph was a true marriage](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/43107/12563). I believe it is the Gospel of James that describes Mary as intending, even from childhood, to be a consecrated virgin. Although the Church doesn't accept that gospel as canonical, I believe it does accept the story as at least pious belief if not Sacred Tradition.

Comment: @MattGutting Thanks!  Just the answer I was looking for.  Yes, I was wondering what the Catholic Church discern about the Gospel of James.

Comment: @cody.tv.weber Not all Protestants deny Mary's perpetual virginity; cf. [What Protestant arguments exist for the perpetual virginity of Mary?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/320/what-protestant-arguments-exist-for-the-perpetual-virginity-of-mary).

Answer (score 3):

Answered by my elder Rick Calvert from Hope Christian Church:

Cody,

The only historical genealogical information of Mary’s family after the birth of Christ are the names of her four other sons.

Scripture states they were named: Joseph, James, Jude, and Simon. These were the half-brothers of Jesus. Half-brothers because Joseph was only the paternal father of Jesus, he was not the material father of Jesus, the Spirit of God was.

The last three of Mary’s son’s mentioned are not to be confused with those who were disciples of Jesus by the same name.

Here are some passages where the other sons of Mary by Joseph are mentioned (Mt. 12:46; 13:55; Mk. 6:3; John 2:12; 7:3, 5, 10; Acts 1:14; 1 Cor. 9:5; Gal. 1:19).

Also, keep in mind that all of the Jewish genealogies dating from Adam to Christ were burned and destroyed by the Romans in 70 A.D. with the destruction of Jerusalem and the Jewish Temple. The purpose of the genealogical records preserved in Scripture was to identify the Messiah when He came, which they fulfilled (Mt. 1:1-17; Lk. 3:23-38), thus, there was no reason for their preservation any longer and God let them be destroyed by the Romans in the late first century. Therefore, no person today can actually prove they are Jewish, nor can they prove their Hebrew tribal genealogy. This also implies that no one can trace their ancestry back to Mary, Joseph, or Jesus, most likely by God’s design.

Warm Regards,
Rick

Comment: Joseph was not the paternal father of Jesus. Joseph had nothing to do with the conception of Jesus.  Joseph married Mary and Jesus became his adopted son.

Comment: @Lesley. I suspect a mental slip caused the wrong word to be used. He's contrasting *paternal father* with *material father*, which makes no sense. (In fact, the phrase "paternal father" makes no sense in the first place.) He probably meant *adoptive father* or something similar.

Comment: @TRiG The wording was 'other sons of Mary _by Joseph_. It was quite specific and quite wrong.

Comment: "are the names of her four other sons" the bible doesn't mention Mary having any sons except for Jesus. Nowhere.

Comment: Sola Gratia, Matthew 12:46 says Jesus had brothers.